# Cannot Send Email in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am creating a function to change password by sending mail, but when I send it, it gives me this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

```
static private Session prepare() {
        // Get properties object
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", MailConfig.HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", MailConfig.SSL_PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", MailConfig.SSL_PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
 
        // get Session
        return Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(MailConfig.APP_EMAIL, MailConfig.APP_PASSWORD);
            }
        });
    }
```

and:

```
static public void sendChangePasswordEmail(String verificationLink, String email) {
        Session session = Mail.prepare();
        
        // compose message
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
            message.setSubject("Orgasnic Website - Change your password");
            message.setText("Please click the following link to change your password: " + verificationLink);
 
            // send message
            Transport.send(message);
 
            System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mail.sendVerifyEmail("asdf", "asdjfasd@baksdf.casoduf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `asdjfasd@baksdf.casoduf` the actual value used?

Comment: Try to change from port 465 to 587.

Comment: This should help you https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth Gmail uses  oAuth2.